# Email rejected by SMTP server

Tags: smtp

I am sending automatic emails with a custom written software. The recipient is VERY interested in receiving these emails, since they actively requested then. However, they are complaining they are not receiving them. I am sending these email using Amazon's SMTP service> I successful send these emails to 25 customers at a time, rotating (meaning that every day a couple of customers drop, and two new customers join). This is a shipping service -- once again, they REQUESTED the updates.

Now... ONE of them doesn't receive the emails.

This is what I get from their email server:

```
The original message was received at Wed, 4 Oct 2023 14:05:51 +0300
from b232-11.smtp-out.ap-southeast-2.amazonses.com [69.169.232.11]
 
   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<XXXX@XXXX.vslhub.YYYYYY.com>
    (reason: 550-sender not allowed or wrong recipient, or message size (13955) exceeds 15K)
 
   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to 10.9.200.7:
>>> DATA
<<< 550-sender not allowed or wrong recipient, or message size (13955) exceeds 15K
<<< 550-or number of sent emails exceeds 5 in the last 24 hours for this
<<< 550-sender:0108018afa5d7367-6a169b6c-8e52-42c7-812d-fecbcd0791e4-000000@ap-southeast-2.amazonses.com
<<< 550 / recipient:XXXX@XXXX.vslhub.YYYYYY.com.
550 5.1.1 <XXXX@XXXX.vslhub.YYYYYY.com>... User unknown
<<< 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
<<< 503-sender not allowed or wrong recipient, or message size (13955) exceeds 15K
<<< 503-or number of sent emails exceeds 5 in the last 24 hours for this
<<< 503-sender:0108018afa5d7367-6a169b6c-8e52-42c7-812d-fecbcd0791e4-000000@ap-southeast-2.amazonses.com
<<< 503-/ recipient:XXXX@XXXX.vslhub.YYYYYY.com.
<<< 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
```

Now:

- The message is tiny.
- We did NOT send 5 emails in 24 hours.
- The recipient is correct (they receive emails sent with Outlook, which is what we are doing now, manually, for updates, but that's kind of insane).

What could the problem possibly be?

Comment: Send the error to the recipient. If their server claims that the sender is not allowed they need to solve it on their end.

Comment: Recipient is VERY unwilling to do anything about it on their end... I am hoping somebody has seen something like this before and could tell me what the problem could be, so I can then tell THEM

Comment: Well, you ruled out all reasons but `sender not allowed`. Most probably the Amazon SMTP service is on a blacklist they are using. You can do nothing to check this, only the recipient can do that by checking their SMTP server logs.

Comment: If they are unwilling to fix this they are not interested enough to receive the messages.

Comment: Does the (possibly rewritten at that point) recipient as it is quoted in the reply you received exactly match what you have been provided as the destination address by the customer? Does the recipient mail provider (if identifiable) also appear in your logs for other recipients?

Comment: 15k sounds suitable for a long gone world where many cared for resource usage. I have mails that have 15k in just *garbage headers* prepended on-route. Have you checked your "tiny" assertion against something received after passing a reasonable number of relays, such as a Google or Microsoft hosted mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to debug the configuration of a remote system you have no control over and with whose administrators you have no business relationship. Even if you knew what was happenning you can't fix it.
2. At least in this case, you are getting a very explicit error message detailling the reason why they are not accepting the email.

> message size (13955) exceeds 15K...or number of sent emails exceeds 5 in the last 24 hours

Perfectly clear, abeit VERY restrictive.

> We did NOT send 5 emails in 24 hours.

Irrelevant. The error message cites the originating host, which you have already told us is part of a shared service.

While the limits cited here are draconian, it is not reasonable to expect the customer to reconfigure the service to allow more traffic through. If you want good email deliverability use a dedicated email service with strong policies on reputation management or run your own on a dedicated IP (with SPF & DKIM).

Answer (score 0):

That `550 /` line strikes me as odd. Messages with further lines are sent with a dash after the status. Are you able to set your own message-id header to prevent that weird line-wrapping that may be confusing the next relay?

---

The SMTP extended status code `X.1.1` (and generally only used as 5.1.1) is reserved for a very clear and specific reason:

> X.1.1
>
> **Bad destination mailbox address**
>
> The mailbox specified in the address does not exist. For Internet mail
> names, this means the address portion to the left of the "@" sign is
> invalid.
>
> -- [IANA - SMTP Enhanced Status Codes Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/smtp-enhanced-status-codes/smtp-enhanced-status-codes.xhtml#table-smtp-enhanced-status-codes-3), introduced via [RFC 3463 Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463.html#section-3.2)

While it is quite possible that the recipient is unable to receive any mail at that message, it is not unreasonably to make an effort in reducing (even not specifically mentioned) potential problems on your end:

- Note also that the local part of a mail address is case sensitive and is allowed to contain rather unusual characters that may have been incorrectly canonicalized encoded on your end (either already on data entry, or later on in the SMTP protocol).
- You may be seeing some mix of messages generated by the receiving end, and messages passed through from its internal relays. I have seen such configurations explain odd combinations of status text (specific) and accompanying message (extremely generic in an attempt to disguise internal routing). Ensuring your messages appear authorized by both SPF and DKIM may help work around problems with (badly configured) forwarding within the recipients networks.

---

Sometimes you can reach the recipients technical staff directly at `postmaster@domain.example`, without the end-user being even aware that their external mail service provider is responsive at that address. If you do so, be certain to provide relevant details (forwarding merely the message *body* of the non-delivery notification may be insufficient, but forwarding the entire message a.k.a "as attachment" likely references the original message-id).